# Replacing GlobalScope.launch with something better

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, completable-future

I'm refactoring the following bit of code that's wrapping a CompletableFuture API into something that can be used with Coroutines, but it's using `GlobalScope.launch { ... }` which is discouraged:

```
suspend fun <T> transaction(f: suspend (Connection) -> T): T {
    val cf = CompletableFuture<T>()
    try {
        this.connectionPool.inTransaction { connection ->
            GlobalScope.launch {
                try {
                    cf.complete(f(connection))
                } catch (e: Throwable) {
                    cf.completeExceptionally(e)
                }
            }
            cf
        }
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        log.error(e.message ?: "", e)
        cf.completeExceptionally(e)
    }
    return cf.await()
}
```

Getting rid of the CompletableFuture and replacing it with CompletableDeferred is the easy part:

```
suspend fun <T> transaction(f: suspend (Connection) -> T): T {
    val cdf = CompletableDeferred<T>()
    try {
        connectionPool.inTransaction { connection ->
            GlobalScope.launch {
                try {
                    cdf.complete(f(connection))
                } catch (e: Throwable) {
                    cdf.completeExceptionally(e)
                }
            }
            cdf.asCompletableFuture()
        }
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        log.error(e.message ?: "", e)
        cdf.completeExceptionally(e)
    }
    return cdf.await()
}
```

The inTransaction API expects a CompletableFuture, I'm assuming this is for backwards compatibility with Java

```
override fun <A> inTransaction(f: (Connection) -> CompletableFuture<A>):
            CompletableFuture<A> =
        objectPool.use(configuration.executionContext) { it.inTransaction(f) }
```

Since I'm outside a CoroutineScope, I can't just call `launch { ... }` and since `f` is a suspend function, that section needs to be inside a CoroutineScope

Wrapping the `connectionPool.inTransaction` inside a `coroutineScope` in order to replace the GlobalScope locks up when it runs ...

```
    try {
        coroutineScope {
            connectionPool.inTransaction { connection ->
                launch {
                    try {
                        cdf.complete(f(connection))
                    } catch (e: Throwable) {
                        cdf.completeExceptionally(e)
                    }
                }
                cdf.asCompletableFuture()
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
```

Similarly with

```
    try {
        coroutineScope {
            connectionPool.inTransaction { connection ->
                async {
                    try {
                        cdf.complete(f(connection))
                    } catch (e: Throwable) {
                        cdf.completeExceptionally(e)
                    }
                }
                cdf.asCompletableFuture()
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
```

Adding some good ol' println debugging:

```
suspend fun <T> transaction(f: suspend (Connection) -> T): T {
        val cdf = CompletableDeferred<T>()
        println("1")
        try {
            println("2")
            coroutineScope {
                println("3")
                connectionPool.inTransaction { connection ->
                    println("4")
                    launch {
                        println("5")
                        try {
                            println("6")
                            cdf.complete(f(connection))
                            println("7")
                        } catch (e: Throwable) {
                            println("8")
                            cdf.completeExceptionally(e)
                            println("9")
                        }
                    }
                    println("10")
                    cdf.asCompletableFuture()
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            log.error(e.message ?: "", e)
            cdf.completeExceptionally(e)
        }
        println("11")
        return cdf.await()
    }
```

Outputs:

```
1
2
3
11
4
10
```

followed by a stacktrace that the query timed out

```
timeout query item <postgres-connection-2> after 73751 ms and was not cleaned by connection as it should, will destroy it - timeout is 30000
```

This means the code inside the `launch` is never executing, similarly with `async`, I'm assuming some thread is getting blocked somewhere.

Replacing the GlobalScope.launch with `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch { ... }` works (similarly with `Dispatchers.Unconfined)`), but is this the correct solution here?
If CompletableFuture is thread-blocking, then this is probably better than the GlobalScope.launch solution ...

```
suspend fun <T> transaction(f: suspend (Connection) -> T): T {
        val cdf = CompletableDeferred<T>()
        try {
            connectionPool.inTransaction { connection ->
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    try {
                        cdf.complete(f(connection))
                    } catch (e: Throwable) {
                        cdf.completeExceptionally(e)
                    }
                }
                cdf.asCompletableFuture()
            }
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            log.error(e.message ?: "", e)
            cdf.completeExceptionally(e)
        }
        return cdf.await()
    }
```

Any suggestions on what the correct way is to get rid of that `GlobalScope.launch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty complicated, but I believe the cause of `launch()`/`async()` not executing is that their parent `coroutineScope()` already finished at this point in time. Notice "11" happens before "4", meaning that you invoked `launch()` after going out of `coroutineScope()`. Which makes sense, because `inTransaction()` starts asynchronous operation, so it returns immediately, without waiting for the inner code. To fix this, you just need to move `cdf.await()` inside `coroutineScope()`.

Another thing that concerns me is that you await on completable that you created by yourself and not the one returned from `inTransaction()`. Note that it may be a totally different `CompletableFuture` and in that case you actually return before the operation completes.

Also, I'm not sure if this manual exception handling for completable is really necessary. `async()` already performs exception handling and wraps the result as `CompleteableDeferred`, then it is converted to `CompletableFuture` which also wraps exceptions. The only thing we have to do is to replace `coroutineScope()` with `supervisorScope()`. Otherwise, `async()` would automatically signal `coroutineScope()` to fail, so the exception handling would totally bypass `inTransaction()` function.

Try this code:

```kotlin
suspend fun <T> transaction(f: suspend (Connection) -> T): T {
    return supervisorScope {
        connectionPool.inTransaction { connection ->
            async { f(connection) }.asCompletableFuture()
        }.await()
    }
}
```

Comment: You should definitely test this solution for exceptional states. I'm aware that exception in `async()`, even if wrapped into `Future`, will probably cancel `coroutineScope()` as well. Maybe it is fine, but maybe we should use `supervisorScope()` here. Or maybe this manual exception mapping is actually required.

Comment: wow, that's beautiful!

I've tested a few errors and it's failing in exactly the same way, existing stuff that's using that transaction { } block continues to work as before, so this is a great solution!!

Thanks @broot!!

Comment: In the meantime I reconsidered this solution and I think we actually have to use `supervisorScope()` (or manual exception handling as you did). The difference is subtle, but important. In the first case `async()` catches the exception and signals `coroutineScope()`, then the latter throws immediately from `await()`. Any exception handing implemented in `inTransaction()` is totally bypassed. When using `supervisorScope()`, `async()` catches, `supervisorScope()` ignores it, `inTransaction()` passes the exception through future and then `await()` fails.

Comment: In the first case `await()` may fail before `inTransaction()` finishes its exception handling. If there is any clean up or something, we return from `transaction()` while this clean up is still going on. Also, if `inTransaction()` handles exceptions in any way, it maps selected exceptions to different ones, etc. (which it probably doesn't), we will ignore its exception handling and still throw the original exception. I updated my answer.